# How to split new line in string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, split

for example .. If I have a text like this

```
214asd
df5df8
d66f66
```

I want to split them into 3 strings using vb.net .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assuming you want to split on new lines - using `String.Split` will return an array containing the parts:

```
Dim parts As String() = myString.Split(new String() {Environment.NewLine},
                                       StringSplitOptions.None)
```

This will be platform specific, so you may want to split on `"\n"`, `"\r"`, `"\n\r"` or a combination of them. `String.Split` has an overload that takes a string array with the strings you wish to split on.

Comment: I really like this way of doing it - however, in one usage of this, I only wanted `parts(UBound(parts))` String (or what I believed it was going to be), and with `StringSplitOptions.None` it would set my variable to `""` - If anyone needs to omit the empty entr[y/ies], use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` for your split options instead.

Answer (score 23):

```
Dim strLines() As String = Clipboard.GetText.Replace(Chr(13), "").Split(Chr(10))
```

I like doing it this way. One can only split on a char but in most cases NewLine is two characters, Carriage Return (0x0D AKA Char 13) and Line Feed (0x0A AKA Char 10). But in other systems it's just a LF. So I simply remove all instances of the CR and split on the LF.

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim strLines As String() = myString.Split(New String() {Convert.ToChar(13), Convert.ToChar(10)}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: you can split the string using an char array.

Answer (score 3):

```
str.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, 
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: @Oded thanks for the edit.. not sure how i missed the code formatting :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim enter As String = vbCrLf
Dim linecount As Integer = 0
Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(yourTextFilePath)
linecount = sr.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar(enter)).Length - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

calling `str.Split(delimter As Char)` Method on a String only allows for Char delimeters.

`Strings.Split(str As String, delimter As String)` allows for a String (e.g. vbCrLf) as delimeter. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=net-7.0)